# Populate a box when a box is checked, how to handle this?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have asked this question before but didn't get any help.

I am going to try to rephrase it a bit.

I have 5 input boxes; let's call them chck1, chck2, chck3, chck4, and chck5.

Each input box has an associated checkbox, let's call them chckbox1, chckbox2, chckbox3, chckbox4, chckbox5. These are in a section called '********Step 3*************

THe spec is that if you enter a number into one of the input boxes and check the associated checkbox in Step 3, the number gets populated into the corresponding box in step 4.

For instance, if i check a checkbox called chckbox1 and enter a number into chck1 in step3, that number gets populated into chck_amt in step 4 as long as the checkbox next to the inputbox in step3 is checked.

If a number is entered in any of the boxes in step 3 but the associated checkbox is not checked, the number doesn't get populated into the corresponding box in step4.

The issue that I have so far is that if I check a box *FIRST* before entering a number, the corresponding  box in step4 gets populated.

If, however, I enter a number into a box in step3 *BEFORE* checking the associated checkbox, that number does NOT get populated into the corresponding box in step4.

Does anyone know how to ensure that whether a number is entered first in step3 or a box is checked first, as long a box is checked, that number needs to get populated into the corresponding box in step4.

Can someone, please help.

I know this is complicated but I am confident gurus here can assist.

Here is the markup for step3 and step4.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
        '**********Step 3******************* 
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck1" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt1','chck1','onetime1','multi1')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell> 
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck2" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt2','chck2','onetime2','multi2')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell> 
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck3" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt3','chck3','onetime3','multi3')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox3" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell> 
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck4" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt4','chck4','onetime4','multi4')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox4" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell> 
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck5" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt5','chck5','onetime5','multi5')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox5" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell> 

                        | 
                        V 

 '**********Step 4******************* 
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck1_amt" runat="server" Width="90px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell> 
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck2_amt" runat="server" Width="90px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell> 
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck3_amt" runat="server" Width="90px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell> 
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck4_amt" runat="server" Width="90px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell> 
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck5_amt" runat="server" Width="90px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell> 


  If chckamttext.Text <> "0" Then
            Select Case chckded
                Case "chck1"
                    If chckBox1.Checked Then
                        chckamtbot.Text = chckamttext.Text
                        chckfed.Text = fedname1.Text
                    End If
                Case "chck2"
                    If chckBox2.Checked Then
                        chckamtbot.Text = chckamttext.Text
                        chckfed.Text = fedname2.Text
                    End If

                Case "chck3"
                    If chckBox3.Checked Then
                        chckamtbot.Text = chckamttext.Text
                        chckfed.Text = fedname3.Text
                    End If

                Case "chck4"
                    If chckBox4.Checked Then
                        chckamtbot.Text = chckamttext.Text
                        chckfed.Text = fedname4.Text
                    End If

                Case "chck5"
                    If chckBox5.Checked Then
                        chckamtbot.Text = chckamttext.Text
                        chckfed.Text = fedname5.Text
                    End If
            End Select
        ElseIf chckamttext.Text = "0" And chckded <> "" Then
            chckamtbot.Text = "0"
            chckfed.Text = ""
        End If
        chckamttot.Text = CDec(chck1_amt.Text) + CDec(chck2_amt.Text) + CDec(chck3_amt.Text) + CDec(chck4_amt.Text) + CDec(chck5_amt.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope something like this works for you.

```
    <form>
<input type="checkbox" ID="chckBox1" name="checkbox1" value="1" onchange="onChange('chckBox','chck','1');" /> chck1 <input id="chck1" type="text" name="chck1" onkeyup="onChange('chckBox','chck','1');"/><br />

<input type="checkbox" ID="chckBox2" name="checkbox2" value="2" onchange="onChange('chckBox','chck','2');"/> chck2 <input id="chck2" type="text" name="chck2" onkeyup="onChange('chckBox','chck','2');"/><br />

<input type="checkbox" ID="chckBox3" name="checkbox3" value="3" onchange="onChange('chckBox','chck','3');"/> chck3 <input id="chck3" type="text" name="chck3" onkeyup="onChange('chckBox','chck','3');"/><br />

<input type="checkbox" ID="chckBox4" name="checkbox4" value="4" onchange="onChange('chckBox','chck','4');"/> chck4 <input id="chck4" type="text" name="chck4" onkeyup="onChange('chckBox','chck','4');"/><br />

<input type="checkbox" ID="chckBox5" name="checkbox5" value="5" onchange="onChange('chckBox','chck','5');"/> chck5 <input id="chck5" type="text" name="chck5"onkeyup="onChange('chckBox','chck','5'); "/><br /><br/>
<br /><br/>



1<input id="chck1_amt" type="text" name="chck1_amt" /><br />
2<input id="chck2_amt"type="text" name="chck2_amt" /><br />
3<input id="chck3_amt"type="text" name="chck3_amt" /><br />
4<input id="chck4_amt"type="text" name="chck4_amt" /><br />
5<input id="chck5_amt" type="text" name="chck5_amt" /><br />


</form>

<script  type="text/javascript">

function onChange(boxID, textID, theNumber){

    //see if box box id is checked 
    var checkStatus = document.getElementById(boxID+theNumber);

    if (checkStatus.checked == true){
        //get value of the textbox id
        var textValue = document.getElementById(textID+theNumber).value;
        //alert(textNumber)
        updateBox(theNumber,textValue);
    }
    //not checked so updating with nothing
    else {
        updateBox(theNumber,'');
    }
}


function updateBox(theNumber,textNumber){
    var updateBox = document.getElementById('chck'+theNumber+'_amt');
    if(updateBox){
        updateBox.value = textNumber;
        console.log('updating: '+theNumber+'  -'+updateBox)
    }
}


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your prompt response user918850, I noticed your input box is different from the one I posted. Mine uses asp.net controls. Does it matter? Will your js still work with my asp.net controls?

Comment: I'm not sure... if your input box ids are the same I don't see why not. Try it out. Or just try to manipulate the same concept with your code. 1. When the checkbox is clicked or the textbox is updated check to see checkbox value. 2. If checkbox == clicked then update the corresponding textbox. If checkbox is not clicked then erase the corresponding textbox.

Comment: They are not the same. They are chck1 through chck5. I am more concerned with the fact that my controls are already using onchange event handler. Perhaps, if you can be kind enough to show my how to merge the my current onchange event with yours, I think Ican make it happen. please see my original post for the step3 code. This thing won't allow me to post the code again for your convenience.

Comment: To me it looks like you named your checkboxes chckBoxN  (chckbox1) your text boxes chckN (chck1) and your results chckN_amt(chck1_amt).

My code is laid out exactly the same. 

Your checkboxes onclick or onchange would need to become

  "onChange('chckBox','chck','1');"

Your text boxes onkeypress or keyup would need to become 

"onChange('chckBox','chck','1');"

as well where you replace 1 with the number of the checkbox. The chckBox parameter is used find the checkbox element. The 2nd parameter 'chck' is used to find the text boxes value

Comment: I would just need an example of how to for instance convert this to what you are explaining. Then I can do the rest:<pre><code><asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="chck1" runat="server" Width="75px" Text = "0" onchange="caltot('tot_amt1','chck1','onetime1','multi1')" AutoPostBack = "True" Ontextchanged = "getAmt"></asp:TextBox> <asp:CheckBox ID="chckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "True" /></asp:TableCell></code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

Can't you handle this in your code behind that if the CheckBox is checked and corresponding TextBox isn't empty then do nothing, otherwise populate the box with value? Something like this:

```
if(chckBox1.Checked && chck1.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
{
//Populate appropriate box
}
```

Comment: Great question Waqas. I actually have this codebehind. This works when you check the checkbox first before entering a value. So, if you can integrate your code with this code I am pasting so that whether a box is checked first before a number is entered or whether a box is checked first, then it works. please see what you can do. Here is the current code behind in vb. Please see the code at the end of Step 4 above. For some reason, I could not paste it here.